# Xamarin.Forms Conflicting references

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried to update Xamarin.Android.Support.V4, GooglePlayServices and after that the following started to appear

```
Warning 3   Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Requests" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1706    3   Workplay.Universal.Droid
```

I tried to do a rollback, but this error is now persistend, I searched for similiar errors but a fix for this doesn't seem to exist, before I updated I didn't have this problem

The error says it is on Project .Droid BUT Nowhere I am referencing System.Net, or System.Net.Requests

Please Help

I tried adding the following to App.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Requests" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:
I ended up creating the project from scratch and copying my code over. took me a while but it seems the warning is gone in the 'new' project

EDIT2:
When I restarted my VS the warning came back

Comment: Jason you getting error or warning? if error then log your details..

Comment: This is warning that visual studio gives,

Comment: look at this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40732/dependent-assembly-version-conflict-binding-redirects

Comment: I tried that at that link, but it didn't help me